# Django Unable to update model based on link click

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to update the model record of a file when it is downloaded from the server.

I am currently using a custom tag that finds the appropriate record and changes the 'used' Boolean to True, however I now realise that this occurs when the link is rendered, not when clicked.

It's pretty clear this is not the way I should be doing this, but haven't found an alternative with my searching. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**profile.html**

```
{% for x in source %}
    {% if forloop.counter <= 4 %}
      <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{ x.video_id }}</h2>
        {% for y in records %}
          {% if x.video_id == y.sourcevideo.video_id %}
            <div class="media-body">
              <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src="{{ y.highlight.url }}" type="video/mp4">
                  Your browser does not support the video tag
                </video>
                <h1>{{ y.highlight_id }}</h1>
                <br>
                <a class="btn" href="{% downloaded y.highlight.url y.highlight_id %}" download>Download</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

**templatetags/analytics.py**

```
from django import template
from highlights.models import Highlight


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def downloaded(url, pk):
    e = Highlight.objects.get(highlight_id=pk)
    e.used = True
    e.save()
    return url
```

**From views.py**

```
class ProfileView(ListView):
    model = Highlight
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'records'
    ordering = ['-date_created']

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Highlight.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['source'] = Video.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user).order_by('-pk')
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what Ajax is for. It's like "when user clicks button, trigger my backend function". Instead of creating whole view just for processing you simply define function that has JSONResponse as return and you're ready to go. One you get to know it, it will improve your django/web dev experience. Here is the [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)